# How do I set logging level in Glassfish?

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-2.x

We are running glassfish 2.1; I want to reduce the chattiness of the logging to server.log but cannot find what config file allows me to do this.  (I'm assuming this will use log4J syntax.)  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glassfish uses JDK (java.util) logging, which is configured in the admin UI, typically running http://server:4848

Depending on whether you installed it as developer profile (the default) or clustering, the logging settings will be two different places.

Developer profile: Application Server/Logging/Log Levels

Cluster profile: Configurations/cluster-config/logger settings/levels

Answer (score 9):

I think the ans need an update in 2018 (after 6 long yrs). The log level option can be viewed by traversing following tabs in left hand side of Glassfish (4.x) Admin Console:

**Configuration -> Server Config -> Logger Settings.**

Then select: **'Logger Levels'**.

[image]

---

[image]

**Note:**

Different Log Levels in order are:

**SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, and FINEST.**

where SEVERE is least detailed and FINEST is most detailed.